# How to copy a row from one sheet to another sheet if the row contains any numbers from a list of numbers?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have 2000 numbers in Column A, some that are duplicates, and I need to copy over the matched numbers into another sheet from a list of possible numbers given in column B. These numbers are just an example:

```
Column A      Column B
122           170
134           289
170           300
170           428
289           584
300           817
300           
428           
438           
584
622
622
817
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Use a MATCH() formula to determine if the number in ColA is in the list, then filter and copy the matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to copy over just the rows that match in Columns A & B then you can try:

```
Sub Compare()

    Dim rowA As Integer
    Dim rowB As Integer
    Dim lastRowA As Integer
    Dim lastRowB As Integer
    Dim spot As Integer: spot = 1

    With ThisWorkbook

    lastRowA = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    lastRowB = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

    .Worksheets(2).Range("A" & spot).Value = "Col A Value"
    .Worksheets(2).Range("B" & spot).Value = "Col B Value"
    .Worksheets(2).Range("C" & spot).Value = "Col C Value"
    .Worksheets(2).Range("D" & spot).Value = "Col D Value"
    .Worksheets(2).Range("E" & spot).Value = "Col E Value"
    .Worksheets(2).Range("F" & spot).Value = "Row found on Col A"
    .Worksheets(2).Range("G" & spot).Value = "Row found on Col B"
    spot = 2

    For rowA = 1 to lastRowA
        For rowB = 1 to lastRowB
            If .Worksheets(1).Range("A" & rowA).Value = .Worksheets(1).Range("B" & rowB).Value Then
                .Worksheets(2).Range("A" & spot).Value = .Worksheets(1).Range("A" & rowA).Value
                .Worksheets(2).Range("B" & spot).Value = .Worksheets(1).Range("B" & rowB).Value
                .Worksheets(2).Range("C" & spot).Value = .Worksheets(1).Range("C" & rowB).Value
                .Worksheets(2).Range("D" & spot).Value = .Worksheets(1).Range("D" & rowB).Value
                .Worksheets(2).Range("E" & spot).Value = .Worksheets(1).Range("E" & rowB).Value
                .Worksheets(2).Range("F" & spot).Value = rowA
                .Worksheets(2).Range("G" & spot).Value = rowB
                spot = spot + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    End With

End Sub
```

This will copy over matching values into Sheet 2 if your original values are in Sheet 1....its just an idea, not sure what is completely the goal by just looking at the post

Edit:
Added data in columns C, D, & E.....pushed 'found' info to the end

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I need. If there are data in columns C D and E, how do I copy all those over as well without displaying where the value was 'found'

Comment: @TerryYe I editted the answer with the changes you requested... data from columns C, D, and E is included. Also, pushed the 'found' information to the end to columns F & G...you can delete those columns if you don't need them

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Kubie